How to write an equation for the intersection of two vectors?
I have an array of values and I wanted to find where to set a cutoff. I felt the best place would be pick the values which go to infinity and from here I end up with two vectors each with a defined set of values. I determine where they intersect by calculating when they swap places as most entries and return the cutoff. The problem is I don’t know how to express this through an equation. I tried to look this up but the I don't really see anyone discussing this.
Here is an example that represents my data and what the output is:




0.6
0.7
0.8
0.9
1




0
0
0
5
25
45


1
0
3
9
15
25


2
3
5
15
15
5


3
5
8
14
8
0


4
9
9
9
11
0


5
15
9
10
4
0


6
25
15
9
0
0


7
30
16
8
0
0


8
37
20
7
0
0


9
39
20
7
0
0


10
45
25
6
0
0



From here, I take 0 and 10 as vectors and compare identifying where the values swap:
v0 = [0,0,5,25,45]
v10 = [45,25,6,0,0]

v10 > v0

Result:
[F, F, T, T, T]

and so 0.8 is returned, as that is where the two vectors intersect.
How to convert this into an equation?

It is not clear to me what you are doing with your data, but for the input [F, F, T, T, T] to generate the output 0.8, use a function that searches for the first T value and returns the index, then output the value at said index from an array containing [0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1].

the array of True and False is to show at what cutoff does half the data result in too high a number compared to too low of a number. In this case, the median is around 0.8

Vectors do not intersect. Do you mean that some particular component of both vectors is the same?

You are correct, I am looking for when the two vectors switch position in regards which has the highest values. When plotting on a graph, it looks like an intersection despite these not being equations
